# Non modal popup using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to learn to create non modal popup using angularjs that will allow to navigate to other webpage when it is still open and it should not blur the window. I found http://yong2579.github.io/ link.

But window is getting blur

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prettify/r298/run_prettify.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/css/bootstrap-dialog.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/js/bootstrap-dialog.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<title>Tabindex</title>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            var dialog = new BootstrapDialog({
                message: 'Custom tabindex.',
                tabindex: 10,
                modal: false,
                title: 'Modeless draggable dialog',
                draggable: true,
                animate: false
            });
            dialog.open();
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The option for a base bootstrap modal to open it with no backdrop is `backdrop: false`.  However, looking at the code for the module in question (https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap3-dialog/1.34.9/js/bootstrap-dialog.js), I can see no way to set that value.

Answer (score 0):

In the context of angular if you are making DOM manipulations (adding or removing elements from the view or modifying their properties) then you should use directives.  For bootstrap modals and other interactive bootstrap elements check out the ui-bootstrap module with lots of directives including modal:

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#!#modal

Modal's are sort of a special case in angular where it makes the most sense to have a service handle opening/closing modals but the docs there should make it pretty clear how to use if not search here or post a new question with issues.

---

When using ui-bootstrap you just include the bootstrap.css and ui-bootstrap-tpls.js file (not the bootstrap.js or jquery.js).  If you don't include jQuery before angular, angular will load jQuery lite (see docs on `angular.element()` for details).